# Contact form with required fields will not submit - using PHP validation

Tags: php, html, forms, validation

My contact form will not submit and send to my email address..

Here is the PHP validation I am using to check required fields and then to send to my email:

```
<?php   

if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
    $body = '';

$body .= 'Name: ' . $_POST['name'] . "\n\n";
$body .= 'Phone: ' . $_POST['phone'] . "\n\n";
$body .= 'Email: ' . $_POST['email'] . "\n\n";
$body .= 'Message: ' . $_POST['message'] . "\n\n";

mail('myemailaddress@gmail.com', 'Contact Form', $body, 'From: no-reply@mycompany.com');
}   

// define variables and initialize with empty values
$nameErr = $addressErr = $emailErr = $messageErr = $spamcheckErr = "";
$name = $address = $email = $message = $spamcheck = "";
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
        $nameErr = "Please enter your name.";
    }
    else {
        $name = $_POST["name"];
    }

    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $emailErr = "Please enter your email.";
    }
    else {
        $email = $_POST["email"];
    }

    if (empty($_POST["message"]))  {
        $messageErr = "Cannot leave message box blank.";
    }
    else {
        $message = $_POST["message"];
    }
    if (!isset($_POST["spamcheck"]))  {
        $spamcheckErr = "Verify you are not spam.";
    }
    else {
        $spamcheck = $_POST["spamcheck"];
    }

}

?>
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
        <div id="contact_input" class="col1">
            <input name="name" placeholder="Name*" type="text" class="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($name);?>">
            <span class="error"><?php echo $nameErr;?></span><br />
            <input name="email" placeholder="Email*" type="email" class="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($email);?>">
            <span class="error"><?php echo $emailErr;?></span><br />
            <input name="phone" placeholder="Phone #" type="tel" class="text" value="<?php echo $phone;?>" />
        </div>
        <div id="contact_input" class="col2">
            <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message*" rows="10" cols="25"><?php echo $message?></textarea>
            <span class="error"><?php echo $messageErr;?></span>
        </div>
        <div id="contact_input" class="col3">
            <input id="spamcheck" type="checkbox" name="spamcheck" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($spamcheck);?>">I am human.*<br />
            <span class="error"><?php echo $spamcheckErr;?></span>
            <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" class="button" /><br />
            <span>*Required Field.</span>
        </div>
    </form>
```

When fields are empty I get the proper error message under each field but I cannot get it to send to my email. However it was emailing me every time I loaded the page, when I made these changes it stopped submitting.

Being new to contact forms with required fields, I can't seem to find the clear answer elsewhere.

I suspect it has something to do with `if (isset($_GET['submit']))` Since that is where I made the change and started having issues.

Comment: Use `isset($_POST['submit'])` instead of `isset($_GET['submit'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I tested your code** and everything checked out, except for this line:

```
if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
```

which just needs to be changed to:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

The issue was in fact using `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`

---

### EDIT

Added a few conditional statements:

```
if (($_POST['name'] &&  $_POST['email'] &&  $_POST['message'] !="") 
&&  isset($_POST["spamcheck"]) !="")
```

Full code (use the full version below):

```
<?php   

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $body = '';

$body .= 'Name: ' . $_POST['name'] . "\n\n";
$body .= 'Phone: ' . $_POST['phone'] . "\n\n";
$body .= 'Email: ' . $_POST['email'] . "\n\n";
$body .= 'Message: ' . $_POST['message'] . "\n\n";

if (($_POST['name'] &&  $_POST['email'] &&  $_POST['message'] !="") &&  isset($_POST["spamcheck"]) !="")
    {
mail('myemailaddress@gmail.com', 'Contact Form', $body, 'From: no-reply@mycompany.com');
    }

}   

// define variables and initialize with empty values
$nameErr = $addressErr = $emailErr = $messageErr = $spamcheckErr = "";
$name = $address = $email = $message = $spamcheck = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["name"])) {

        $nameErr = "Please enter your name.";
    }
    else {
        $name = $_POST["name"];
    }

    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $emailErr = "Please enter your email."; 
    }
    else {
        $email = $_POST["email"];
    }

    if (empty($_POST["message"]))  {
        $messageErr = "Cannot leave message box blank."; 
    }
    else {
        $message = $_POST["message"];
    }
    if (!isset($_POST["spamcheck"]))  {
        $spamcheckErr = "Verify you are not spam.";
    }
    else {
        $spamcheck = $_POST["spamcheck"];
    }

}

?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
        <div id="contact_input" class="col1">
            <input name="name" placeholder="Name*" type="text" class="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($name);?>">
            <span class="error"><?php echo $nameErr;?></span><br />
            <input name="email" placeholder="Email*" type="email" class="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($email);?>">
            <span class="error"><?php echo $emailErr;?></span><br />
            <input name="phone" placeholder="Phone #" type="tel" class="text" value="<?php echo $phone;?>" />
        </div>
        <div id="contact_input" class="col2">
            <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message*" rows="10" cols="25"><?php echo $message?></textarea>
            <span class="error"><?php echo $messageErr;?></span>
        </div>
        <div id="contact_input" class="col3">
            <input id="spamcheck" type="checkbox" name="spamcheck" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($spamcheck);?>">I am human.*<br />
            <span class="error"><?php echo $spamcheckErr;?></span>
            <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" class="button" /><br />
            <span>*Required Field.</span>
        </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This does deliver an email, however it delivers the email even if the required fields are empty.

Comment: I left certain fields empty and it did work for me. Give me a minute, I'll double check. @rileychuggins

Comment: Ok, see my **EDIT** @rileychuggins it just needed a few (extra) conditional statements.

Comment: Thank you! Works great - Thanks for putting it into context for me. Visual learner, I can see and (sort of) understand the error checking that precedes the `mail()` function. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I will say, it was a bit of a challenge (lol), but I'm glad it made your day :) cheers @rileychuggins

Comment: I wanted to make it as simple as possible, without having to add or modify extra lines, and that seemed to be the simplest way of achieving this. @rileychuggins

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `?submit` to the `action` string in your form or else `$_GET['submit']` will be unset.

```
<form method="post" action="?submit">
```

or you can change the `isset` function to check the `$_POST` var instead of the `$_GET` var

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

EDIT: Here's what you should do with your validation script

```
if (!empty($_POST['submit'])) {
    $error = array();
    if (empty($_POST['email'])) $error[] = 'Please enter your email';
    // and so on...

    if (empty($error)) {
        // Send email script goes here
    }
}
```

And then for your user display upon any errors:

```
if (!empty($error)) foreach ($error as $e) echo '<p class="error">'.$e.'</p>';
```

This allows you to add more error messages as often as you'd like with ease, and uses the empty property of an array to verify the lack of error in validation.

Comment: `action="?submit"` ? you sure about that? For a `GET` maybe, but `POST`?

Comment: Tested. It will submit to itself with the URL http://www.example.com/file.php?submit=submit

I'm offering two solutions, but I'd obviously pick the latter

Comment: The OP may as well just use `action=""` when used as self, having everything set inside one file. However, this practice isn't always the best method.

Comment: Yes, and that's why I ditched `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` as well. As long as OP changes context after a form is submitted successfully, a self-submitting file would work well, especially for server-side form validation where you can just echo the `$_POST` values back to the user.

Comment: Well, the OP's code checked out in my testing, yet all that needed to be changed was `if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {` to `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {`

Comment: @sjagr changing `$_GET` to `$_POST` delivers the email, but delivers even if the required fields are empty. I need it to deliver only when the required fields are filled in. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should change the flow of your validation. It's quite messy, standby for my edit

Comment: Here's a better way to go about validating your script in my edit. Your original code would always submit empty values no matter what because there's no error checking preceding the mail() function. I'm not sure how you think `$_GET` factors into the validation process.

Comment: Thanks again, seems as though php may be too new for me to actually understand. Would my send email scripts be the same as I have listed above? Would I not use an `else` below the `if (empty($_POST['email'])) $error[] = 'Please enter your email';`?

Comment: You don't have to unless you need to do something when the previous condition isn't satisfied. For example, where were you planning on using `$email` and why can't you just use `$_POST['email']`? If you're putting it back as `<input value="<?php echo $email; ?>" />` to conserve code length then that's a useful step, but you could achieve the same thing by doing `<input value="<?php if (isset($_POST['email']) echo $_POST['email']; ?>" />`

Answer (score 0):

I don't understndand    `if (isset($_GET['submit']))` in fact. Why is it there?

```
$field1 = NULL;
 $field2 = NULL;

    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $field1 = $_POST["field1"];
    $field2 = $_POST["field2"]; 
    //etc
    mail ("youremail", "yoursubject", "$field1 $field2 $field3 etc.");
        }
```